# CSS Grid column width depending on content

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I am rendering CSS Grid with one column per row that will render either:

- nothing
- button (let's call it type 1) of width 120px
- button (type 2) of width 185px
- both button types, in which case they should both be 185px width

When I render nothing, all rows will render nothing in that column, so I would like that column to have 0 width, and other columns should split remaining space.

When button type 1 is rendered, I want that column to have width of 120px, and rows that don't render the button, should display empty space of that width (to not break layout)

When I render both type of buttons (so some rows contain button type 1, some contain button type 2 and some contain nothing) I would like that column to take width of wider button - 185px.

I tried achieving that with setting `minmax(0, 185px)` in `grid-template-columns`, but had no luck, since in that case it always sets the width to `185px`. Any ideas on this would be appreciated

Columns are placed in a grid wrapper, that has style

```
.CSSGrid {
    grid-template-columns:
48px minmax(100px, 3fr) 140px 140px minmax(200px, 1fr) minmax(100px, 1fr) max-content 50px;
}
```

Column that contains buttons is the next to last one, value `max-content` (I was just experimenting)

Example: https://codepen.io/idjuka/pen/wvarPrN
In this example, if I would to remove the last row (with wider button) i would like the upper button to have smaller width. Is it possible to have width 100% on the button, but determine the width of column with css grid - if content width is xyz px -> column width should be xyz px,

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: I added the code bit that's causing me problems. Pasting the whole code wouldn't make sense, since it is too complex

Comment: For a question to be checked/answered we need code to be able to reproduce the issue. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Syfer thank you for pointers, added example on codepen.